# Function returning a pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

I solved the next challenge on hacker rank. I searched the internet and found something about function pointers (which I thought will help me to solve the challenge), but I could not solve it. I looked in the discussion on the site and I have found a way to solve the problem. It did not pass all the test cases on the site, but it worked for 5 out of 7. I somehow copied some code, ran it, made some change, ran it and so on until I got the following version. The thing is that I still do not understand how and why does it work and if this approach is the best used in this case. This is my code:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int* solve(int a0, int a1, int a2, int b0, int b1, int b2, int *result_size){
    static int ar[2] = {0, 0};
    *result_size = 2;
    ar[0] += a0 > b0;
    ar[0] += a1 > b2;
    ar[0] += a2 > b2;
    ar[1] += b0 > a0;
    ar[1] += b1 > a1;
    ar[1] += b2 > a2;
    return ar;
}

int main() {
    int a0; 
    int a1; 
    int a2; 
    scanf("%d %d %d", &a0, &a1, &a2);
    int b0; 
    int b1; 
    int b2; 
    scanf("%d %d %d", &b0, &b1, &b2);
    int result_size;
    int* result = solve(a0, a1, a2, b0, b1, b2, &result_size);
    for(int result_i = 0; result_i < result_size; result_i++) {
        if(result_i) {
            printf(" ");
        }
        printf("%d", result[result_i]);
    }
    puts("");


    return 0;
}
```

This is the link to the problem: [https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/compare-the-triplets/problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/compare-the-triplets/problem/%22Compare%20the%20triplets%22).

What I do not understand is that `int *solve`. How does that work? I read the question about function pointers on SO, but I didn't get it. And why must I use `static` array? If the array is not static my compiler (gcc) says that I can't return address of local variable. Also in main shouldn't `int* solve` have memory allocated?

(Should I add the "text" of the problem here instead of adding the link?)

Comment: This is a function returning a pointer. No function pointers here.

Comment: Believe if you've never used/seen a function pointer, seeing one for the first time will look far more bizarre than what you have here.

Comment: The idea of code challenge sites (whether a formal competition or not) is to solve the problem by yourself or by research (but not by copying code from "tell" sites). "I somehow copied some code" but the idea is to write your own code, not ask how to solve your bad plagiarism. Please ask a specific question about C.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you don't understand code you have ripped off.

Comment: @WeatherVane My question was not about solving the challenge. It was specifically about C. I am not primarily interested to solve the challenge. I am interested to understand the things I asked. Have I asked "how to solve the challenge?"? I use the challenges because I want to learn and sometimes I do not know what should I learn. I do not learn because I want to solve these challenges. I am voting this question to be answered. Does SO have an own way of learning and the one used by me in this case is wrong? Let me know. Thank you!

Comment: @WhozCraig Please recommend me a good introductory book or course to function pointers and functions returning pointers in C.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing about function pointer here. `solve` is a function which returns an `int *` (pointer to `int`) type.

> And why do I must use static array?

Returning a pointer to an automatic local variable leads to undefined behavior, therefore `static` is used to make it static variable.

Other way around is to allocate space dynamically in function `solve`

```
int *ar = malloc(sizeof (int) * 2);
memset(ar, 0, sizeof(ar));
```

Answer (score 2):

static variables are life-timed until the program is terminated. This is a function returning pointer to integer. So the program executes without issues. While the semantics are slightly changed when the static variables are under a shared object,the above example is a plain vanilla flavor.